# SSL handshake exception coming intermittently in android

Tags: android, ssl, https

I am getting following SSL exceptions from my app when requesting via volley from Android

- SSL Handshake Exception com.android.volley.o:
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
  java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
  certification path not found.
- SSL Handshake Exception com.android.volley.o:
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
- SSL Handshake Exception com.android.volley.o:
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

These exceptions are coming intermittently for users. I am not sure if its a server issue since for same server,  IOS app is not throwing any SSL error.

All above exceptions are IO exceptions and is coming at below mentioned highlighted line of "BasicNetwork.Java":

```
  @Override
    public NetworkResponse performRequest(Request<?> request) throws VolleyError {
        long requestStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        while (true) {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            byte[] responseContents = null;
            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = Collections.emptyMap();
            try {
                // Gather headers.
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                addCacheHeaders(headers, request.getCacheEntry());
                httpResponse = mHttpStack.performRequest(request, headers);
                StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                responseHeaders = convertHeaders(httpResponse.getAllHeaders());
                // Handle cache validation.
                if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED) {

                    Entry entry = request.getCacheEntry();
                    if (entry == null) {
                        return new NetworkResponse(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED, null,
                                responseHeaders, true,
                                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
                    }

                    // A HTTP 304 response does not have all header fields. We
                    // have to use the header fields from the cache entry plus
                    // the new ones from the response.
                    // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5
                    entry.responseHeaders.putAll(responseHeaders);
                    return new NetworkResponse(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED, entry.data,
                            entry.responseHeaders, true,
                            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
                }

                // Handle moved resources
                if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY || statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
                    String newUrl = responseHeaders.get("Location");
                    request.setRedirectUrl(newUrl);
                }

                // Some responses such as 204s do not have content.  We must check.
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_NO_CONTENT && httpResponse.getEntity() != null){
                  responseContents = entityToBytes(httpResponse.getEntity());
                } else {
                  // Add 0 byte response as a way of honestly representing a
                  // no-content request.
                  responseContents = new byte[0];
                }

                // if the request is slow, log it.
                long requestLifetime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart;
                logSlowRequests(requestLifetime, request, responseContents, statusLine);

                if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 299) {
                    throw new IOException();
                }
                return new NetworkResponse(statusCode, responseContents, responseHeaders, false,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                attemptRetryOnException("socket", request, new TimeoutError());
            } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
                attemptRetryOnException("connection", request, new TimeoutError());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Bad URL " + request.getUrl(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                int statusCode = 0;
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = null;
                if (httpResponse != null) {
                    statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                } else {
                    **throw new NoConnectionError(e);**
                }
                if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY || 
                        statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Request at %s has been redirected to %s", request.getOriginUrl(), request.getUrl());
                } else {
                    VolleyLog.e("Unexpected response code %d for %s", statusCode, request.getUrl());
                }
                if (responseContents != null) {
                    networkResponse = new NetworkResponse(statusCode, responseContents,
                            responseHeaders, false, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
                    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED ||
                            statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN) {
                        attemptRetryOnException("auth",
                                request, new AuthFailureError(networkResponse));
                    } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY || 
                                statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
                        attemptRetryOnException("redirect",
                                request, new AuthFailureError(networkResponse));
                    } else {
                        // TODO: Only throw ServerError for 5xx status codes.
                        throw new ServerError(networkResponse);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new NetworkError(networkResponse);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to know exact reason behind this.

Comment: it seems that the server certificate is inadequate